# Less CSS is not compiled in Grails 3 when deploying as WAR

Tags: grails, gradle, less, grails-3.0

I have a grails app in the following environment :

| Grails Version: 3.0.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

I have the following plugins installed :

com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0
com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7

In my local dev enviroment, my less files are successfully being compiled and everything is working as expected.  However, when deploying to production, the less is not being pre-compiled into css (as far as I can tell).

My assumption that the local environment is fine is due to the less-asset-pipeline plugin defaulting to the less4j compiler.

I've tried following the documentation on the following to Git repos :

https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline
https://github.com/bertramdev/less-asset-pipeline

If I run .gradelw assetCompile, I see that the asset pipeline includes regular css files but that the references to less files are being ignored (or are failing).

Here is the gradle build file and I've removed some entries to make it easier to find if anything is missing :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }

        // Custom maven repo for the cloudinary plugin
        // maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "0.1"
group "mchq.admin"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/repo" }

    // Custom maven repo for the cloudinary plugin
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/infinit/infinit-opensource" }

    maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"


    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC2"

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37'

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    compile 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'


    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

task stage() {
    dependsOn clean, war
}
tasks.stage.doLast() {
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/distributions")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/assetCompile")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/distributions")
    delete fileTree(dir: "build/libs", exclude: "*.war")
}
war.mustRunAfter clean
```

Strangely, If I add anything to the assets {} section of the build file, all building fails within terminal and it just hangs.

Any pointers on ensuring this pre-compilation of less files would be greatly welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your `build.gradle` should look in regards to the less plugin

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {        
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'
    }
}
dependencies {
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:2.6.7'
}
```

You should also get the latest version of asset pipeline

Comment: Hi James, fantastic, things are being compiled now it seems.  I should perhaps open new thread for this but is there any way to exclude asset subdirectories from compilation whilst still allowing them to be packaged into the production war?  I've determined the excludes directive to add to build.grade.

Comment: Also, it seems compilation of my own .less files doesn't process the files in order of inclusion by asset pipeline directives.  By that I mean, it is compiling a buttons.less file that references a variable I've placed in a separate variables.less file.  As buttons.less is compiled first, it hasn't reached the variables.less file.  Is this capability beyond the plugins compilation method?

Comment: @RobinM You need to exclude all directories that you don't want to be compiled individually. Personally I did this by setting the plugin to exclude anything under a directory that starts with an _. I then renamed my bootstrap/fontawesome to that format. An important thing to remember is to specifically include any font files as they will 404 otherwise under that strategy.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much for your help on this one.  You've save me a huge amount of time and frustration. I went for the same naming convention as you, then excluded all 3rd party add-ons that caused compilation issues, then re-included font directories, jpg, png files as needed.  Works a dream. Thanks